# dbUnit dtd error: The declaration for element type "dataset" must end with '>'

Tags: java, xml, junit, dtd, dbunit

I work with dbUnit for the first time. I took the sample dtd from [here](http://www.dbunit.org/components.html#XmlDataSet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT dataset (table+) | ANY>
<!ELEMENT table (column*, row*)>
<!ATTLIST table
    name CDATA #REQUIRED
>
<!ELEMENT column (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT row (value | null | none)*>
<!ELEMENT value (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT null EMPTY>
```

I get the following error:

> org.dbunit.dataset.DataSetException: Line 2: The declaration for element type "dataset" must end with '>'.

What does that mean? I'm confused because I took the original dtd and secondly there *is* a '>' at the end of the dataset definition.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the first line to:

```
<!ELEMENT dataset (table+ | ANY)>
```

will make the syntax correct.

However, the model may just as well be:

```
<!ELEMENT dataset ANY>
```

as the "ANY" context specification will match table elements anyway (and more, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-logical-struct)

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to `<!ELEMENT dataset (table+)>`, now it works :)